# MySQLI SELECT with multiple clauses for epoch timestamps selection

Tags: mysql, select

I have epoch timestamps into "PART_EPOCH" column, table name is "crud_mysqli"

- I would like to select associated "PART_ID" value for the next FUTURE timestamps. (avoid a research into past timestamps)

The following MySQLI query should select the MIN (next) value within the future : > now.

But it does not return anything.
It does return expected return if i state clauses seperately,
combining clauses as below returns no result.

Would you please tell me what is wrong here :

```
    // Find next event PART_ID name :
    // SELECT lowest (next) PART_ID value in the future (do not select winthin past PART_EPOCH values)
    $query = "SELECT
    PART_ID
    FROM crud_mysqli
    WHERE (PART_EPOCH = (SELECT MIN(PART_EPOCH) FROM crud_mysqli))
    AND (PART_EPOCH > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
    ";
```

Comment: Put the second condition into the subquery

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel  the following does not return any result either. `SELECT PART_ID FROM crud_mysqli WHERE (PART_EPOCH = (SELECT MIN(PART_EPOCH) FROM crud_mysqli) AND PART_EPOCH = (SELECT PART_EPOCH > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())))`

Comment: I mean it should be in the same subquery. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (PART_EPOCH = (SELECT MIN(PART_EPOCH) FROM crud_mysqli))
```

Here you say to only take the entry with the lowest timestamp, which is probably somthing in the past.

```
AND (PART_EPOCH > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
```

And here you say, that it should be in the future. The two conditions are excluding each other, if you have any entry with the timestamp in the future.

So you need to put the second condition into the subquery:

```
SELECT
PART_ID
FROM crud_mysqli
WHERE PART_EPOCH = (
    SELECT MIN(PART_EPOCH) 
    FROM crud_mysqli
    WHERE PART_EPOCH > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
)
```

That means: "take the entry with the lowest timestamp in the past"

However.. you can as good do the following:

```
SELECT PART_ID
FROM crud_mysqli
WHERE PART_EPOCH > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
ORDER BY PART_EPOCH ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The result would only differ if you have two entries with the same timestamp. In that case the first query would return both of them - the second query only one.

Comment: Paul, you are right many thanks for this clear explanation. It works.

Comment: @Laurent See the second query. It might be the better way.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you very much.